# Intuitive microscopic explanation of Lenz's Law?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

Consider a horizontal wire loop through which a magnet is dropped. I understand the macroscopic explanation. The moving magnet generates an electric current in the wire loop(counterclockwise when viewed from the top). The wire loop's current then generates a magnetic field in the opposite direction(up). Certainly I have read about the conservation of energy as the 'justification' for this behavior. But from a microscopic point of view I am puzzled about what's going on.

I tried to visualize a screw being turned into a piece of frictionless wood. If I push the screw down, it turns clockwise. If I turn the screw clockwise it still goes down. If I were to make a screw that obeys Lenz's Law, it would have right hand threads when I turn it clockwise it would move downwards. But when I push down on the Lenz screw it would have a tendency to turn counterclockwise.

I read this post

[Quantum Mechanics of Lenz's Law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59611/quantum-mechanics-of-lenzs-law)

and even read J.D.Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics chapter 6.6
'Derivation of the Equations of Macroscopic Electromagnetism'

He starts off with the microscopic Maxwell equations. But this just kicks the can down the road. The third equation is:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf E +  \frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} =0$$

The fourth equation is:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf B - \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t} =\mu _{0} \mathbf j$$

With these equations, he then goes on to generate time and space averaging integrals to give the macroscopic equations.

I guess I am asking WHY on a quantum mechanical level these two equations are this way. Certainly, I know Feynman's admonition that WHY can be a meaningless question, it really just asks for a substitution of some variables for others. And when there is no data at the level of detail we are looking for, then why is meaningless.

This post seems to come close

[Explaining Lenz's Law without conservation of energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77865/explaining-lenzs-law-without-conservation-of-energy)

but it talks about the 'flattening' and tilting' of electrons due to Lorentz force?

Some idiosyncratic ('random') ideas that cross my head are

1. Does a moving magnetic field only affect the spin of an electron according to a left hand rule (in other words translational motion is not directly affected)?
2. Does electron motion only occur when an electron changes its spin?
3. Does a magnetic field generated from its spin act to counteract the magnetic field of its motion?

This sounds like nonsense to my conscious thought process because to test it, I would have to be able to fix the electron so it doesn't 'spin'  but still allow translational motion. If I could so 'fix' all the electrons in a copper pipe, then a magnet would fall through this copper pipe unimpeded.

Certainly mechanistic ideas were disapproved starting in the late 19th century with the theory and observations of quantum mechanics. So I am looking for an intuitive quantum mechanical explanation of the relationship of an electron and magnetic force.

Comment: You asked WHY those two equations are that way. I'm not sure what you would consider a satisfying answer to WHY, but I'll offer a thought thinly disguised as a request for clarification: Maxwell's equations (all of them) can be written as $F_{ab}=\partial_a A_b-\partial_b A_a$ and $\partial_a F^{ab}\propto J^b$, and the pattern of signs and derivatives is basically dictated by Lorentz symmetry (special relativity). No quantum physics is needed for this. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Why is special relativity relevant? I am looking for a quant mech explanation

Comment: Whether quantum or not, the reason for the form of the two equations you showed comes from Lorentz symmetry. Without Lorentz symmetry, quantum physics won't help answer your question. If you're asking for an example of a quantum model that respects those equations (in the classical approximation), then one answer is: quantum electrodynamics (QED). It's Lorentz-symmetric. Or you can consider a non-relativistic approximation to QED that still respects those equations, but a quantum model doesn't need to respect them -- unless it's supposed to be an approximation to a Lorentz-symmetric model.

Comment: On the other hand, we can also consider a quantum version of the electromagnetic field by itself (QED without matter), constructed to satisfy the quantum version Maxwell's equations. That would be the *simplest* quantum model. Would that answer the WHY question? The way I interpreted your question, it wouldn't, because it's still assuming equations of the same form -- just quantum instead of classical. I focused on the question "WHY on a quantum mechanical level these two equations are this way," and the Lorentz symmetry gives the simplest answer that I know, even on a quantum level.

Comment: Well I thought I was missing something about Lorenz symmetry but the Wikipedia entry is quite clear.

Comment: In relativistic physics, Lorentz symmetry, named after Hendrik Lorentz, is an equivalence of observation or observational symmetry due to special relativity implying that the laws of physics stay the same for all observers that are moving with respect to one another within an inertial frame.

Comment: So I am not understanding what makes you say ‘Lorentz symmetry’. When I start a current in a loop in one direction, the induced magnetic north points a certain way and it grows in a particular direction as the current increases. But if stop the current and just apply a meter, then take a magnet and push it through the loop in the same direction as the field grew before, I get a current flowing in the wire opposite to the direction  it flowed In the first part of the experiment.

Comment: So I part 1 of the experiment if the electrons flow first the the field moves one way. If the field moves first in the same way as before, the electrons move the other way.

Comment: This is what I don’t get. It’s like having a board balanced on a knife edge and seeing the following behavior- pushing on the left side of the balanced board makes the right side move up, but pushing on the right side of the board makes the left side move down.

Comment: I wasn't claiming that Maxwell's equations can be derived from Lorentz symmetry, only that "the pattern of signs and derivatives is basically dictated by Lorentz symmetry" in the sense that they can't be arbitrarily changed, because I thought that might be the question. If you're asking why E&M exists at all, then it's not clear from the question what kind of answer you would consider satisfying. We have quantum electrodynamics, which is maybe a little more satisfying because its structure is constrained by renormalizability as well as by Lorentz symmetry... would that answer "why"?

Comment: At your suggestion, I am starting with qed. Thank you